# How can I make my navigation bar look like this?

Tags: iphone, ios

I was looking at custom table cell tutorials and found this [site](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/11/20/how-to-design-a-custom-uitableviewcell-from-scratch/). I really like the navbar effect with the blue halo but have no idea how to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava I'm pretty sure he's talking about the navigation bar...

Comment: This is most likely done purely in Photoshop, and applying the image as the navigation bars background image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably have an custom image as the background, with custom image buttons too. Here's a good example on how to do that: http://designm.ag/tutorials/designing-a-custom-iphone-app-navigation-bar/ If you need more info, just comment! Hope this helps! (Also this isn't exactly the style like in the picture but [PrettyKit](https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit) is awesome at stuff like this!)